# jinja2 render string in single quote

Tags: jinja2, templating

Facing issue while generating CF manifests through jinja2 templating. jinja2 is unable to output env property under single quotes in manifest.

The template.yml.j2 template file has this,

```
JBP_CONFIG_JAVA_MAIN:'{java_main_class: "com.test.example.GeneralService", arguments: "setup.yml"}'
```

The final manifest.yml has missing single quotes,

```
JBP_CONFIG_JAVA_MAIN: {java_main_class: "com.test.example.GeneralService", arguments: "setup.yml"}
```

Expected output in manifest,
'`{java_main_class: "com.test.example.GeneralService", arguments: "setup.yml"}'` **with quotes**

I am really not getting why single quote is getting omitted after rendering the output manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jinja, it's tricky but easy to do, try this in your template file -

```
JBP_CONFIG_JAVA_MAIN: "'{java_main_class: "com.test.example.GeneralService", arguments: "setup.yml"}'"
```

Works for me.